# Position absolute for card-flip in bootstrap 4 container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a card flip effect using the following code within a row of the bootstrap 4 container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="card-container col-sm-4">
            <div class="card card-front" >
                <img class="card-img-top" src="image/1.JPG" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">1</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-back" >
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p  class="font-weight-light">
                        Some back text
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-container col-sm-4">
            <div class="card  card-front" >
                <img class="card-img-top" src="image/2.JPG" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">2</h5>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-container col-sm-4">
          <div class="card  card-front">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="image/3.JPG" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">1</h5>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second and third card are not yet have backside. But the backside of those cards will be like the first card. Here the CSS

```
.card-container{
    position: relative;
    perspective: 200rem;
}

.card-container:hover .card-front{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-container:hover .card-back{
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card{
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.9s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

The problem is when I use `position: absolute` the height of the `container` becomes 1px. How to fix this? Or is there a better way to achieve this? I have tried adding `position: relative` to `row` and `container` but still didn't work.

Comment: @`Poramet` **.card-front** class should be **relative** postion and **.card-back** class in *absolute* position with  **height:100%** + Overflow for content scrolling and also make a parent div of this **card** and set **position:relative**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.card-front** class should be **relative** position and **.card-back** class in **absolute** position with width, height, top, left and **overflow** property using for more content show by scrolling. So from this technique to **.container** height will auto.
I hope this below snippet will help you lot.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container my-2">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="card-container col-sm-4 my-3">
      <div class="position-relative">
        <div class="card card-front">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/22ff22" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">1</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-back">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p  class="font-weight-light">Some back text #1
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
              cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
              proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container col-sm-4 my-3">
      <div class="position-relative">
        <div class="card card-front" >
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/ffff22" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">2</h5>    
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-back" >
          <div class="card-body">
            <p  class="font-weight-light">Some back text #2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container col-sm-4 my-3">
      <div class="position-relative">
        <div class="card card-front">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/2222ff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">3</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-back">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p  class="font-weight-light">Some back text #3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container col-sm-4 my-3">
      <div class="position-relative">
        <div class="card card-front">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/ff2222" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">4</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-back" >
          <div class="card-body">
            <p  class="font-weight-light">Some back text #4 <br>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
              cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
              proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.container{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
}
.card-container {
  perspective: 200rem;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.9s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid lightpink;
}
.card-front{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.card-back {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.card-container:hover .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card-container:hover .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is an image on the front and nothing on the back... this is the reason... put the same image on the back and hide it

working snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-container col-sm-4">
      <div class="card card-front">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQGYY.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">1</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-back">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQGYY.png" alt="Card image cap" style="visibility:collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="font-weight-light">
            Some back text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .card-container {
    position: relative;
    perspective: 200rem;
  }
  
  .card-container:hover .card-front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  .card-container:hover .card-back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  
  .card-back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  .card {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.9s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border: 1px solid lightpink;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Height your of `container` is 0px and doesn't work for me. I want  `container` to have the same height as the card.

Comment: `container` will be `0px` in height because its children have `position:absolute`... if the cards are fixed in size, we can do `.container{
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height:224px;
    }` - in case the height for the cards can be different, use JavaScript !!